# Snakemake tutorial error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name' "

Tags: python, attributeerror, snakemake

When I try running the first command (snakemake -np mapped_reads/A.bam) from the Step 1 of Snakemake tutorial (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/basics.html) I get the following error:

```
snakemake -np mapped_reads/A.bam
Building DAG of jobs...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jeremi1504/mambaforge/envs/snakemake-tutorial/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 701, in snakemake
    success = workflow.execute(
  File "/home/jeremi1504/mambaforge/envs/snakemake-tutorial/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 1066, in execute
    logger.run_info("\n".join(dag.stats()))
  File "/home/jeremi1504/mambaforge/envs/snakemake-tutorial/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 2191, in stats
    yield tabulate(rows, headers="keys")
  File "/home/jeremi1504/mambaforge/envs/snakemake-tutorial/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tabulate/__init__.py", line 2048, in tabulate
    list_of_lists, headers = _normalize_tabular_data(
  File "/home/jeremi1504/mambaforge/envs/snakemake-tutorial/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tabulate/__init__.py", line 1471, in _normalize_tabular_data
    rows = list(map(lambda r: r if _is_separating_line(r) else list(r), rows))
  File "/home/jeremi1504/mambaforge/envs/snakemake-tutorial/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tabulate/__init__.py", line 1471, in <lambda>
    rows = list(map(lambda r: r if _is_separating_line(r) else list(r), rows))
  File "/home/jeremi1504/mambaforge/envs/snakemake-tutorial/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tabulate/__init__.py", line 107, in _is_separating_line
    (len(row) >= 1 and row[0] == SEPARATING_LINE)
  File "/home/jeremi1504/mambaforge/envs/snakemake-tutorial/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/rules.py", line 1138, in __eq__
    return self.name == other.name and self.output == other.output
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I followed all the commands from the set-up section (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/setup.html) and everything seems to be installed properly. The required environment is active and I had no problems activating it. I also build my snakefile according to the instructions.

What can be the source of the problem? I understand what causes the usual 'AttributeError' but I do not know why it occurs in a tutorial that is supposed to work without any modifications from the user.

How can I overcome this error? Is it a matter of installing additional dependencies? If so, which ones? Or is the tutorial broken/outdated/malformed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hit this bug https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1899

Try upgrading snakemake to the latest version or, if can't, downgrade `tabulate` to 0.8.